# C - error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: matthewmpp
 *
 * Created on November 7, 2010, 2:16 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
prime numbers.
version4
should tell whether a number is prime or not prime.
by using other prime numbers.
 */

int input_func() {
    char line[100];
    int n_input;

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter a whole number.\n");
        fgets(line, sizeof (line), stdin);
        sscanf(line, "%d", &n_input);

        if (n_input >= 0)
            break;

        return (n_input);
    }
}

int ifstatements_func(n_ifstate)
int n_ifstate;
{
    if (n_ifstate == 0) {
        printf("The number, %d, is not prime and has no factors.\n", n_ifstate);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (n_ifstate == 1) {
        printf("The number, %d, is not prime.\n", n_ifstate);
        printf("The factors of %d, is %d.\n", n_ifstate, n_ifstate);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (n_ifstate == 2) {
        printf("The number, %d, is a prime.\n", n_ifstate);
        printf("The factors of %d, are 1 and %d.\n", n_ifstate, n_ifstate);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (n_ifstate == 3) {
        printf("The number, %d, is a prime.\n", n_ifstate);
        printf("The factors of %d, are 1 and %d.\n", n_ifstate, n_ifstate);
        exit(1);
    }
    return (n_ifstate);
}

int square_root_func(n_prmfnc)
int n_prmfnc;
{
    int i; //counter

    float sq_root_f;
    int sq_root_i;

    int primes[100];
    int length_primes;

    primes[0] = 2; /*first prime is 2.*/
    primes[1] = 3; /*second prime is 3.*/
    length_primes = sizeof (primes);

    //printf ("before.sq_root.value of n_prmfnc=%d\n", n_prmfnc);
    sq_root_f = sqrt(n_prmfnc);
    sq_root_i = sq_root_f;
    //printf ("prmfnc.after.sq_root\n");
    //printf ("value of sq_root=%.3f\n", sq_root_f);
    //printf ("value of sq_root=%d\n", sq_root_i);

    return (sq_root_i);
}

int prime_func(sq_root_pf, n_pf)
int sq_root_pf;
int n_pf;
{
    //printf ("in.pf.beginning.of.func.sq_root_pf=%d\n", sq_root_pf);
    //printf ("in.pf.beginning.of.func.n_pf=%d\n", n_pf);

    int factor_counter = 0;
    int factor_temp;
    int prime_counter = 0;
    int prime_flag = 0;

    int primes_pf[100];
    int length_primes_pf = 0; //counter
    int i; //counter

    primes_pf[0] = 2;
    primes_pf[1] = 3;
    primes_pf[2] = 5;

    length_primes_pf = 3;
    //printf("length_primes_pf=%d\n", length_primes_pf);

    //printf ("before.for.in.pf\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= length_primes_pf; ++i) {
        //printf ("after.for.in.pf\n");
        if (primes_pf[i] == 0)
            printf("primes_pf=0");
        else {
            if (primes_pf[i] <= sq_root_pf) {
                //printf("primes_pf.i=%d, sq_root_pf=%d\n", primes_pf[i], sq_root_pf);
                //printf("before.modulus.in.pf\n");
                factor_temp = n_pf % primes_pf[i];
                //printf("after.modulus.in.pf\n");
                //printf("value.of.factor_temp=%d\n", factor_temp);
                if (factor_temp == 0) {
                    ++factor_counter;
                    //printf("value.factor_counter=%d\n", factor_counter);
                } else
                    ++prime_counter;

                if (factor_counter == 0 && prime_counter > 0) {
                    prime_flag = 1; /*yes, number is prime.*/
                    primes_pf[length_primes_pf + 1] = n_pf;
                    //printf("length_primes_pf=%d\n", length_primes_pf);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    if (prime_flag == 1) {
        printf("The number, %d, is prime.\n", n_pf);
        printf("The factors of %d, is 1 and %d.\n", n_pf, n_pf);
        exit(0);
    } else
        printf("The number, %d, is not prime.\n", n_pf);

    if (prime_flag == 0)
    pfactorization (primes_pf, length_primes_pf, n_pf);

    return (prime_flag);
}

int pfactorization(primes_fac, length_primes_fac, n_fac)
int primes_fac[];
int length_primes_fac;
int n_fac;
{
    int i;
    int j;

    int result;
    int n_temp;

    int z_array;
    int length_z_array=0;

    for (i=0; i<=length_primes_fac; ++i) {
        result = n_fac%primes_fac[i];
        if (result == 0) {
            n_temp = n_fac/primes_fac[i];
            z_array[length_z_array]=primes_fac[i];
            ++length_z_array;
        }
    }

    printf ("The prime factorization is:");
    for (j = 0; j < length_z_array; ++j)
        printf("%d\n", z_array[j]);
}

int factors_func(n_ff)
int n_ff;
{
    int i;
    int j;

    int result;

    int factors[100];
    int length_factors = 0;

    for (i = 2; i < n_ff; ++i) {
        result = n_ff % i;
        if (result == 0) {
            factors[length_factors] = i;
            ++length_factors;
        }
    }

    printf("The factors for %d are:\n", n_ff);
    printf("1\n");

    for (j = 0; j < length_factors; ++j)
        printf("%d\n", factors[j]);

    printf("%d\n", n_ff);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    int n_main1; //number from input
    int n_main2; //number after if statements
    int sq_root_main; //square root of number from function
    int prime_flag_main; //value of 1 if it is a prime

    n_main1 = input_func();
    //printf("main.after.input.function=%d.\n", n_main1);

    n_main2 = ifstatements_func(n_main1);
    //printf("main.after.ifstatments.function=%d\n", n_main2);

    sq_root_main = square_root_func(n_main2);
    //printf("main.after.square_root_func_func=%d\n", sq_root_main);

    prime_flag_main = prime_func(sq_root_main, n_main2);
    //printf("main.after.prime_func=%d\n", prime_flag_main);

    factors_func(n_main2);



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ vim prime6.c
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ cc -c prime6.c
prime6.c: In function ‘pfactorization’:
prime6.c:171: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
prime6.c:178: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

STATEMENT;
The function: pfactorization is supposed to find the prime factorization of a number.
It is called at the bottom of function: prime_func.
Data is being passed from prime_func to pfactorization.
Code was working fine before I added this function.

QUESTION:
I don't understand this error message.
What does it mean and how should I fix it?

SOLVED:
int z_array[100];
Thanks.

Comment: The `171` and `178` are line numbers.  In your editor (vim?) go to that line to see what code the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: This would have been easier for others to answer if you'd marked lines 171 and 178, rather than leaving people to count or guess.  Something to remember for the future.

Comment: In vim, `:171` and `171G` from normal mode will take you to line 171.  If starting vim, giving a `+171` on the command line will start Vim at line 171.  Also, in the future, **please** reduce your code to the smallest reproducible test case.

Comment: Why on earth are you using K&R function parameter declarations?  And `pfactorization` needs to be moved above `prime_func`.

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen old-style function declarations in forever.

Comment: What are lines 171 and 178?  or have you not even identified the lines causing the errors yet?

Comment: Nathon: Yeah, I think this is the first time I've seen K&R style functions this millennium!

Answer (score 5):

`z_array` is declared to be type `int`. `int` is neither an array nor a pointer :)

I'm guessing you meant to make it an `int*`.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell which line is the correct line, but what that means is that you're using the indexing operator "[]" on something that isn't the correct type.

```
blah[foo]
```

blah must be of type array, or pointer.

Edit: Your code:

```
int z_array;
.....
      z_array[length_z_array]
.....
   printf("%d\n", z_array[j]);
```

z_array is declared as an int, int's can't be indexed

Answer (score 2):

`z_array` is just declared as an `int`, and you are trying to index it using square brackets like an array.

Answer (score 2):

z_array is not an array of integers it is a single integer. You cannot subsript it like z_array[var]. To declare an array you can do int z_array[100] for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
int z_array;
z_array[length_z_array]=primes_fac[i];
printf("%d\n", z_array[j]);
```

`z_array` is not an `int[]` or an `int*`, thus `z_array[i]` is nonsensical.

I suspect you may have intended to write

```
int *z_array = malloc((length_primes_fac + 1) * sizeof(int));
...
free(z_array);
```

or something similar.  I haven't dug into the surrounding code to determine if that's realy the correct size or not.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have solved your immediate problem, but your program is crawling with more subtle problems.  I have taken the liberty of rewriting it for you.  There is a reason for every change I made, even the ones that seem trivial.  Please read it carefully and consider why I did what I did.  I am happy to answer *specific* questions about the changes.

```
/* factor.c - produce the prime factorization of a number.
   Uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

static unsigned char *
compute_sieve(unsigned long root)
{
    unsigned char *sieve = malloc(root + 1);
    unsigned long i, j;

    /* all numbers are prime till proven otherwise */
    memset(sieve, 1, root + 1);

    /* 0 and 1 are not prime */
    sieve[0] = 0;
    sieve[1] = 0;

    for (i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
        if (!sieve[i])
            continue;
        for (j = 2; i*j <= root; j++)
            sieve[i*j] = 0;
    }

    return sieve;
}

static unsigned long *
compute_factors(unsigned long number, const unsigned char *sieve,
                unsigned long root, int *isPrime)
{
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned long *factors = calloc(root + 1, sizeof(unsigned long));

    *isPrime = 1;

    /* trial division by each prime in turn, starting with 2.  */
    for (i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
        if (!sieve[i])
            continue;
        while (number % i == 0) {
            *isPrime = 0;
            number /= i;
            factors[i]++;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}

static void
factor(unsigned long number)
{
    unsigned long root, i;
    unsigned char *sieve;
    unsigned long *factors;
    int isPrime;

    /* weed out base cases */
    if (number <= 3) {
        printf(" %lu\n", number);
        return;
    }

    /* sieve needs to go up to the square root of NUMBER */
    root = (unsigned long) floor(sqrt(number));
    sieve = compute_sieve(root);
    factors = compute_factors(number, sieve, root, &isPrime);

    if (isPrime)
        printf(" %lu\n", number);
    else {
        for (i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
            while (factors[i]) {
                printf(" %lu", i);
                number /= i;
                factors[i]--;
            }
        }
        if (number > 1)
          printf(" %lu", number);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    free(sieve);
    free(factors);
}

static void
usage(char **argv)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s NUMBER\n"
            "NUMBER must be a non-negative integer\n",
            argv[0]);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long number;
    char *endptr;

    if (argc != 2) {
        usage(argv);
        return 1;
    }

    number = strtoul(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    if (endptr == argv[1] || *endptr != '\0') {
        usage(argv);
        return 1;
    }

    factor(number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're upgrading his K&R C, why stop at C89?  :-)

Comment: C99 doesn't really give you anything for this problem? ;-)